# Less memory usage in global constants

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

There's are few ways to define a global constants: define, static const, extern... etc.
What is the one that consume the less memory?
I've a lot of constants in my .pch file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommendation is to use the constant. Unless you are in a very memory constrained environment the wasted memory if you don't use it is minute. The frameworks are full of such constants.

However to aid understanding: the constant will use memory for the string itself and one pointer sized chunk of memory for the constant's own storage - typically 4 or 8 bytes. Unless that is you don't use it and the compiler or linker is able to remove it; this is unlikely if the constant is globally accessible, more likely if it is a file scope (static) constant. The memory usage of the macro is also compiler/linker dependant, but probably more than the constant - consider that after macro processing the compiler sees multiple uses of the same literal string, possibly in different files.

So unless you know your compiler/linker well, and it doesn't change, then you are considering likelihoods:

1. The constant will more than likely consume a small fixed amount of memory.
2. If not used the macro will consume no memory.
3. If used exactly once the macro will consume about the same memory as the constant, the difference, if any, will be negligible.
4. If used more than once in the same file the macro may use more memory.
5. If used more than once in more than one file the macro will probably use more memory.

In summary, if the string is used the constant will probably use less memory and at most a negligible amount more, so don't worry about it unless you are very memory constrained; or until memory becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to say that the scope of your constants is more important than the memory they consume.

Second, depends the content of your constant, `#define` which is a preprocessor action can be good cause it directly inject the result into your code. It's good if you have small usage of your constants. Otherwise, in the hand it's all the same. Because it's const, your object will be stored at runtime once (or depend of the scope, once per class or per object).

But really, unless you have hundred of thousands vars, it shouldn't really have an impact on memory. Trust the compiler to take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

extern will consume less memory than static, because static creates one constant per file with imported header, extern creates one constant per application.